# How to link design-time TWebActions with a structure of TObjects?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, design-time, superobject

I have a web service with an ever growing number of TWebAction items defined at design time on a TWebModule, and coupled to OnAction events.

Requests are HTTP GETs through the URL and responses are 'handcrafted' JSON data, i.e. composed at runtime with statement like `'TSuperObject'.S['errormessage'] := lErrMsg;`

I want to change this to HTTP POST requests with JSON data, and then all request/response JSON structures being (de)serialized from/to proper Objects (and maybe records) using SuperObjects TSuperRttiContext *AsJSON* and *AsType* methods.

**How can I create data structures for mapping/linking my new 'Objects to be JSON (de)serialized' with the design time TWebactions**? These objects will all be different (some properties can be in a common ancestor), and may contain object or record properties themselves (things like `FData: Array of TSubObject` [which SuperObject can serialize fine]).

Note: There is already a quick-and-dirty enumerated type that I have used to gather timing statistics (which needs to be maintained too), this could be integrated as well.

```
type
   TWebAct = (
    ttinfo,
    ttlogin,
    ...
    ttgetcostitemlist,
    ttgetvacationplanning
    );
```

Basically, I want to minimize the number of places where I need to do maintenance whenever a new TWebAction is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TWebAct` enumeration to put together an array of records that tie the web actions to their respective request and response structures.

```
type
  // ancestor class for all requests and responses
  TJSONStructure = class(TObject);

  TJSONRequest = class(TJSONStructure);
  TJSONRequestClass = class of TJSONRequest;

  TJSONResponse = class(TJSONStructure);
  TJSONResponseClass = class of TJSONResponse;

const 
  WEBACT_STRUCTURES: array[TWebAct] of 
    record
      RequestClass: TJSONRequestClass;
      ResponseClass: TJSONResponseClass;
    end = (
      {ttInfo}   (RequestClass: TInfoRequest; ResponseClass: TInfoResponse)
    , {ttLogin}  (RequestClass: TLoginRequest; ResponseClass: TLoginResponse)
    ...
  );
```

Comment: Finally a good use for using metaclasses - let's see if I can get my head around those ;-)

Comment: LOL, if you need help, just holler. My head is wrapped around them pretty well now. :)

Comment: I'm hollering here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125462/how-to-call-object-method-for-any-object-in-my-metaclass

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127452/serializing-json-object-for-an-instance-of-a-metaclass

Comment: Heard you! Not sure I can answer, but I'll have a look.