# How to call object method for any object in my metaclass?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, metaclass

I have basically this object structure:

```
TJSONStructure = class(TObject);

TReqBase = class(TJSONStructure)
private
   token: Int64;
public
   procedure FillWithTemplateData; virtual;
end;

TReqLogin = class(TReqBase)
private
   username,
   password: String;
   module  : Integer;
public
   procedure FillWithTemplateData; override;
end;

procedure TReqBase.FillWithTemplateData;
begin
   token := ...;
end;

procedure TReqLogin.FillWithTemplateData;
begin
   inherited;
   username := ...;
   password := ...;
   module   := ...;
end;

type
   TWebAct = (ttlogin,
              ttsignin);

TReqClass = class of TReqBase;

const
   cWebActStructures: Array[TWebAct] of
   record
      RequestClass : TReqClass;
   end
   = (
      { ttlogin  } (RequestClass: TReqLogin;),
      { ttsignin } (RequestClass: TReqSignIn;)     // Not in definitions above
     );
```

Now I do:

```
var
   lWebAct       : TWebAct;
   lRequestClass : TReqClass;
begin
   for lWebAct := Low(TWebAct) to High(TWebAct) do
   begin
      lRequestClass := cWebActStructures[lWebAct].RequestClass;
```

and I want to call

```
lRequestClass.FillWithTemplateData;
```

in order to execute `TReqLogin.FillWithTemplateData` when lWebAct = `ttlogin` etc.
But it won't compile: `E2706 This form of method call only allowed for class methods.`

I do understand the reason (the text of the compiler message) but how can I fix this so that TReqLogin.FillWithTemplateData gets executed when lWebAct=ttlogin etc **without having to handle a list of TReqLogin, TReqSignIn types in the code (again)**?

Comment: You've got a class, and want to call an instance method. So, you need to get an instance. How do you propose doing so?

Comment: That's exactly my question. First I need a TReqLogin instance, then a TReqSignIn instance etc. I'd hoped one of you wizards would come up with a trick ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lRequestClass` is a class reference. You can call `class` methods on it, but not instance methods. And `FillWithTemplateData` is an instance method.

You need to have an instance to call an instance method. So instantiate one:

```
var 
  req: TReqBase; 
....
req := lRequestClass.Create; 
try
  req.FillWithTemplateData;
  ...
finally
  req.Free;
end;
```

If you develop the classes so that they need to perform work in their constructors then you must introduce a virtual constructor to `TReqBase`. And override that in derived classes. That's the only way that you can make sure that the derived constructor runs when you are instantiating from a class reference.

Perhaps your system requires instances to be instantiated in some other way, I cannot tell from here. No matter what, however you instantiate then, you need an instance to call an instance method.

Comment: Thank you! I overlooked ("could not believe" may be better phrased) that creating the instance would create an object of type TReqLogin. I thought it would create an object of type TReqBase since 'after all' TReqClass = Class of **TReqBase**. This meta stuff is abstract ;-)

Comment: @Jan `lRequestClass.Create` may well create an **object** of type `TReqLogin`, but your **reference variable** is of type `TReqBase`. In other words it is perfectly possible to have a reference variable of one type that refers to an object of a different type. In fact that's what makes polymorphism tick.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an Interface Reference instead?

```
type

  IReqBase = Interface(IInterface)
  ['{B71BD1C3-CE4C-438A-8090-DA6AACF0B3C4}']
    procedure FillWithTemplateData;
  end;

  type
   TWebAct = (ttlogin,
              ttsignin);

  TForm59 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FReqList: Array of IReqBase;
    procedure CreateBaseList;
    procedure ClearBaseList;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TJSONStructure = class(TInterfacedObject);



  TReqBaseClass = class of TReqBase;

  TReqBase = class(TJSONStructure, IReqBase)
  private
     token: Int64;
  protected
    class function ReqClass: TReqBaseClass; virtual; abstract;
  public
     Constructor Create; virtual;
     procedure FillWithTemplateData; virtual;
     class function ReqBase: IReqBase;
  end;

  TReqLogin = class(TReqBase)
  private
    Fusername,
    Fpassword: String;
    Fmodule  : Integer;
  protected
    class function ReqClass: TReqBaseClass; override;
  public
     Constructor Create; override;
     Destructor Destroy; override;
     procedure FillWithTemplateData; override;
  end;

  TReqSignIn = class(TReqBase)
  private
    Fusername,
    Fpassword: String;
    Fmodule  : Integer;
  protected
    class function ReqClass: TReqBaseClass; override;
  public
     Constructor Create; override;
     Destructor Destroy; override;

     procedure FillWithTemplateData; override;
  end;

var
  Form59: TForm59;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm59.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  IReqBase(FReqList[integer(CheckBox1.Checked)]).FillWithTemplateData;
end;

procedure TForm59.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateBaseList;
end;

procedure TForm59.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBox1.Checked then
    TReqSignIn.ReqBase.FillWithTemplateData
  else
    TReqLogin.ReqBase.FillWithTemplateData;
end;

procedure TForm59.ClearBaseList;
begin
  SetLength(FReqList, 0);
end;

procedure TForm59.CreateBaseList;
begin
  if High(FReqList) = Ord(High(TWebAct)) +1 then
    ClearBaseList;

  SetLength(FReqList, Ord(High(TWebAct)) + 1 );
  FReqList[ord(ttlogin)] := TReqLogin.ReqBase;
  FReqList[ord(ttsignin)] := TReqSignIn.ReqBase;
end;

procedure TForm59.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateBaseList;
end;

procedure TForm59.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClearBaseList;
end;

{ TReqLogin }

constructor TReqLogin.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FUserName := 'Rick';
  FPassword := 'Test';
  Fmodule := 100;
end;

destructor TReqLogin.Destroy;
begin
  Form59.Memo1.Lines.Add('Destroyed: ' +ClassName);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TReqLogin.FillWithTemplateData;
begin
  inherited;
  Form59.Memo1.Lines.Add(Fusername);
  Form59.Memo1.Lines.Add(FPassword);
  Form59.Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(FModule));
end;

class function TReqLogin.ReqClass: TReqBaseClass;
begin
  Result := TReqLogin;
end;

{ TReqBase }

constructor TReqBase.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  Token := -1;
end;

procedure TReqBase.FillWithTemplateData;
begin
  Form59.Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Token));
end;

class function TReqBase.ReqBase: IReqBase;
begin
  Result := ReqClass.Create;
end;

{ TReqSignIn }

constructor TReqSignIn.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FUserName := 'Peterson';
  FPassword := 'TestPW';
  Fmodule := 101;
end;

destructor TReqSignIn.Destroy;
begin
  Form59.Memo1.Lines.Add('Destroyed: ' +ClassName);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TReqSignIn.FillWithTemplateData;
begin
  inherited;
  Form59.Memo1.Lines.Add(Fusername);
  Form59.Memo1.Lines.Add(FPassword);
  Form59.Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(FModule));
end;

class function TReqSignIn.ReqClass: TReqBaseClass;
begin
  Result := TReqSignIn;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Not yet. I had looked at interfaces for some sort of multiple inheritance idea, but wanted to avoid them because for this part I already have to master JSON (de)serialization, metaclasses, maybe generics ;-)

Comment: Interfaces references are pretty simple...copy my code into a new project...and you can see how they work...also look at Button3click